# Unsupported field datatype: metadata

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, metadata, block, rails-admin

I have this error message:

```
Unsupported field datatype: metadata.
Extracted source (around line #23):

21      end
22
23  configure :block, :metadata
24      
25  configure :sticky, :metadata do
26      view_helper :check_box
```

I'm doing this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/benoitbenezech/rails-admin-overbest-practices) about the gem rails_admin. And in the slide 29 I put that in the Post and than has this error.
My files:

/lib/rails_admin/metadata.rb

```
require 'rails_admin/config/fields/base'

module RailsAdmin
    class Metadata < RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::base
        RailsAdmin::Config::Fields::Types::register(self)

        def value
            raise 'No metadata!' unless bindings[:object].respond_to?(:metadata)
            bindings[:object].metadata[method_name]
        end

        def allowed_methods
            'metadata'
        end

        def parse_input(params)
            params['metadata'] ||= bindings[:object].metadata
            params['metadata'] [method_name] = params.delete(method_name)
        end
    end
end
```

/models/blog/post.rb

```
class Blog::Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
    belongs_to :user

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments

    serialize :metadata, Hash

    rails_admin do 

        configure :user do
            visible do
                bindings[:controller].current_ability.can? :edit, User
            end
        end

        configure :comments do
            visible do
                bindings[:controller].current_ability.can? :edit, Blog::comment
            end
        end

        configure :block, :metadata
        configure :sticky, :metadata do
            view_helper :check_box
        end

        configure :published, :metadata do
            view_helper :check_box
        end

        configure :priority, :metadata do
            view_helper :number_field
            defaul_value 0
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/rails_admin/metadata"` in the head of rails_admin initializer.

Or add the `lib` folder in the rails autoload paths.

In your `config/application.rb` add:
`config.autoload_paths  = %W(#{config.root}/lib)`

Btw the serialized datatype in rails_admin is already implemented: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/serialized.rb

Comment: Thank you dalpo, for help me! the app works perfectly.